# Ruby regex without global flag

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a regex problem. I have this regex:

```
/(https|http):\/\/(kwagmire)\.(com)\/(embed)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/i
```

and this captures correctly on https://regexr.com but on Ruby on Rails anything with

```
http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam
```

returns a truthy value, I think because it sets it with the `global` flag which I don't want.

I tried `match` and `scan` but still the same returns a truthy value if the link is seen. I just want it to be specific.

```
https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam < I want to return success this one is ok when testing on console

http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam < I want to return success also this on returns good

https.evil.com/http://jsitor.com/embed/1QgJVmCam < I want to return fail or nil, this one passes returns all match

facebook.com < I want to return fail or nil this one is good because it's failing

https://google.com < I want to return fail or nil also this good failed
www.twitter.com < I want to return fail or nil

http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/?onload(alert('asdfadsf')) < I want to return fail or nil, this one also is failing, good

http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/   onload(alert('asdfadsf')) < I want to return fail or nil, this one returns match too but should fail

http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/?onload(alert('asdfadsf')) < I want to return fail or nil, this one returns match too, this should fail
```

basically I want this `https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam` all else should return nil or false. is there an easy way without looping? I think the solution on this one is remove the global flag or `g` but do you have that option? If so why if I do this?

see the `i` after `/`

```
/(https|http):\/\/(jsitor)\.(com)\/(embed)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/i.match("http://jsitor.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/ onload(alert('asdfadsf'))")
```

and returns but this should fail

```
#<MatchData "http://jsitor.com/embed/1QgJVmCam" 1:"http" 2:"jsitor" 3:"com" 4:"embed" 5:"1QgJVmCam">
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve? Can you provide some test links of what you want to match and what links shouldn't match?

Comment: @allenbrkn check text before `<` I edited it

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not a question about Rails. This is a question about pure Ruby.

Comment: Rather than try to write a regex, which for URI is complex, use Ruby's URI class which already has it written and it works, and which allows you to break a path into its components and then check them individually. In particular, look at [`split`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html#method-c-split) and [`parse`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html#method-c-parse).

Comment: You need to state your question in terms of what you want to achieve, *without reference to a regular expression*. That is, you have a number of strings you want to test. Only one passes the test. What is the test?  That's how you need to frame your question. After you have done so you can present the regular expression you tried, and explain why it doesn't work. Lastly, forget about speculating as to why the regular expression doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need either `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of your regex, or better yet `\A` and `\Z` to mark the beginning and end of the entire string (`^` and `$` work as long as it is a single line).

This is telling Ruby that it must match from beginning to end.  Also the 'i' at the end isn't necessary and may yield incorrect results.

The following modified regex will work.

`/\A(https|http):\/\/(kwagmire)\.(com)\/(embed)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?\Z/`

Note that besides the `\A` and `\Z` I also added `\/?` which allows for an optional `/` at the end of the url. I also removed the `i` at the end because you don't actually want the *entire* regex to be case insensitive.  The last part `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` already is case insensitive by how it is declared with a-z and A-Z.

`myregex.match("http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCa/?onload(alert('asdfadsf'))")`
 **returns** `nil`

`myregex.match("http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/")`
 **returns** `#<MatchData "http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/" 1:"http" 2:"kwagmire" 3:"com" 4:"embed" 5:"1QgJVmCam">`

Comment: yow sir I think this is it. this is all I want. I knew there's a simple way without looping this because I know what the url is going to be. Ive used similar way in javascript before i just forgot. thank you!  @randall

Comment: also i added this \A and \Z but on https://regexr.com/ its saying that literal A thats why i didn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess,

```
(?im)^https?:\/\/(?:w{3})?kwagmire\.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$
```

might simply work OK.

#### Test

```
re = /^https?:\/\/(?:w{3})?kwagmire\.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$/im
str = 'https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam
http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam
https.evil.com/http://jsitor.com/embed/1QgJVmCam
facebook.com
https://google.com
www.twitter.com
http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/?onload(alert(\'asdfadsf\'))
http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/   onload(alert(\'asdfadsf\'))'

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### Output

```
["1QgJVmCam"]
["1QgJVmCam"]
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YAfhbi/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YAfhbi/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: sorry sir this doesn't work. I was thinking of like `regex_without_global.match('https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam')` return truthy 

`regex_without_global.match('https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/?evilevil')` return nil

Comment: With ruby, `^` and `$` match always the start and end of the line, and the m modifier allows the dot to match newlines.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte but it just give me an empty array when I tried his approach tho

Answer (score 0):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Ruby has the [URI module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html) which actually parses URI's and understands them. It will beat the socks off almost any regular expression when it comes to actually working with URIs.

Input:

```
input = ["https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam", "http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam", "https.evil.com/http://jsitor.com/embed/1QgJVmCam", "facebook.com", "https://google.com", "www.twitter.com", "http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/?onload(alert('asdfadsf'))", "http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam/   onload(alert('asdfadsf'))"]
```

```
require 'uri'

# This assumes that the id is 9 characters
re =  /\A\/embed\/[\d|a-zA-Z]{9}\/?\Z/.freeze
clean = input.map do |line|
  begin
    uri = URI(line)
    if uri.host == 'kwagmire.com' && uri.path =~ re && !uri.query
      uri.to_s
    end
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    nil
  end
end.compact
```

Output:

```
["https://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam", "http://kwagmire.com/embed/1QgJVmCam"]
```

This lets you use a far simpler regular expression to verify the path, you could also just use `uri.path.split('/')` and forgo a regex completely. It also guarantees that you are dealing with a valid URI.